# How to check if Status bar is expanded?

Tags: adb

I would like to determine, using ADB, whether Status bar is expanded/collapsed. I'm just looking for a way to check whether it's expanded or not, not what caused it to expand/collapse.

I know that there is `cmd statusbar` that can either expand or collapse the Status bar but I couldn't find a way to check its current state.

What I've tried so far:

- comparing the output of `dumpsys window windows| sed -n '/Window .*StatusBar.*:/,/Window .*:/p'`
- comparing  the output of `dumpsys statusbar` -> `mDisableRecords.size` is the most promising key, but I can't understand what exactly its value mean.

Can this check be done through any other command or am I missing something?

Comment: grep `StatusBarWindowController` from logcat. Whatever last entry you would grep will tell you whether expanded flag is set to True or False.